# What is the origin of the claim of the 27 million Soviets dead in WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, revisionism

All throughout the existence of the USSR, there was always the claim that the number of USSR citizens who died in WWII was 20 million.

Lately, I am seeing a persistent claim that that number was 27 million.  That's quite a difference.  And it's never presented as an estimate.  People bring this number up with decimal-point precision when discussing WWII.

I am **NOT, NOT, NOT, NOT asking if the claim is true.**

I am curious what is the origin of this "27.x million" claim.  What is the FIRST source for it.  Was it some scholarly revision which did the 1st work and gained traction?

I am sure people can point to a lot of supporting sources which confirm it, but that's not what I am asking.  I am asking about what is the 1st source for it.

Comment: What research have you done so far, and/or are the references in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties_of_the_Soviet_Union) insufficient?

Comment: From the link provided by @shoover : *"During the period of Glasnost, the official figure of 20 million war dead was challenged by Soviet scholars. In 1988–1989, estimates of 26 to 28 million total war dead appeared in the Soviet press."* Also, one scholar *"acknowledged that the components used to compute losses are uncertain and disputed."* The article also has a chronological table of casualty estimates by scholars, starting in 1988.

Comment: I guess the 20 million is the simple figure, which happens to be rounded down.

Comment: 20 million came from Khrushchev, though that was corrected later by Brezhnev who admitted to 25 million. 26-28 million were officially presented in 1993 - https://encyclopedia.mil.ru/encyclopedia/history/more.htm?id=11359251@cmsArticle
Though in 2021 Russian Duma published documents suggesting that number is closer to 42 million. I still think it's not all of it, but I think it's the best we'll get.

Comment: This may sound like channelling Stalin but: if you look at the WP page already cited (also in other languages, like ru?), you see that the estimates vary _widely_  (between 7–50 million!), and do so repeatedly going up & down. So, why focus on 'exactly' "27"? What difference does that make? That's asking for an illusion of precision, as we see Timashev/'48 or Eason/'59 with already estimating >25 mill, but 25–27 gaining more traction after 85/91 _for other scholars._ (Cambridge Hist of Russia: "25"±1!) Looks like the most useful answer might be a thorough frame challenge?

Comment: @LаngLаngС because lately I've seen people using "27 million" number as canon.  I was wondering what brought that on.

Comment: @James and "10" would be a nice round-down of the number of the Soviet republics of the Soviet Union, but that was not something any considered.  It was canonically accepted (in the Soviet Union) that the Soviet Union lost 20 mil people due to WWII.  Mind you that roughly 50% of *all* Soviet movies were about WWII.  So the war's subject matter was very ingrained in culture (including pop culture).  So this number was just a large part of how people viewed their own contribution to human civilization.  It was "we lost 20 mil, so...."